# Rules Table/Method in Access, has anyone heard of it?

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, rules

We have 5000 Products all with separate prices and 200 customers who could all have different prices for each of these products. We need some way of allowing the sales team to change prices for individual customers or products or ranges/categories without affecting the rest of the prices for the other customers.

Right now this is done by copy and pasting a price list, making manual changes and importing the new price list as a category. This is not what we want.

I have been told about a method of achieving the same thing simply by having a set of prices stored in access and then a rules table that applies a rule based on information such as:

- Customer
- Product
- Category
- Price
- Percentage

This would allow us to store one line of information for each price change instead of an entire list of prices just to make one amendment.

Basically I am asking if anyone has ever heard of this method and where we can find more information about this method and how it works/how to apply it?

Thanks in advance,
Bob P

Comment: Why not the normalised way of using a price/customer table which stores product id, customer id, price and date?

Comment: Because with 5000 products and 200 customers that would be 1,000,000 records that the system would need to store and check through to get a single price back?

Comment: Also this kind of rule method allows more flexible temporary pricing structures as well as long term changes? Also, it makes it easier to change prices for customers and track the changes they make?

Comment: @BobP: The system would not have to check 1,000,000 records - only the rows which are connected to the current customer. Remou is correct.

Comment: Does "Customer A" receive the same percent discount (or surcharge) for all 5000 products?  Or is it 10% off for one product, no discount on a different product, and so forth?

Comment: Yeh Hans, it can be that bespoke, where we have one customer who has just one different price to everyone else, and we could have 100's of customer like that, with just one or two minor changes to the pricing structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a table which is basically each customer's special price list. The table would consist of a customer number, a part number and a price. Only prices which differ from the general price list should appear in this table.

In terms of finding what a part's price should be for a given customer, first the program would check in this table to see whether there is an entry for the given part and customer. If no record is found, the general price list is used.

Comment: This is similar to how we want to create this new method, however instead of storing all of those records, just store one simple line that applies to a customer and then a product/category and then a price change (percentage or actual price input). That is searchable, this would allow our sales team to search for price rules which they have applied and edit/delete them.

Comment: It seems as if your program does not issue SQL queries but rather looks at the data as a simple worksheet which has to be searched, one row at a time. With SQL, there can only be one row which matches the product/customer combination, so the access time (no pun intended) is negligible.

Comment: Would your method allow us to add a percentage discount for example? Instead of just a new price? And would it also allow us to discount a category, a product, a category for a customer, a product for a customer or just a customer?

Comment: The table would store data for each product/customer combination. The simplest implementation would be to store a price for each combination, although it's also practical to store a multiplier/discount factor for the same combination - ie master pricelist shows $100 for product A, special table shows 5% discount for [product A, customer #55], so the final price for [product A, customer #55] would be $95. Discounting on a customer wide basis (ie customer #62 always receives a 10% discount) should be done via the customers table because it is an property of the customer.