# Applying calculations based on a number of criteria stored in separate tables?

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access, database-design

What I need to create is a table containing "Rules" such as overriding prices and applying percentage increases to the price of stock.

For Example:

Sales Price is select from the table containing information about products, then the system needs to check another table to see if that Customer/Product/Product Category has any price rules set against it, such as percentage discount or set price to be overridden to.

How do I get access to first of all check if the customer in question exists in the table, then if the product exists and then if the category exists; and then apply the price change that is stored?

So far we have a PriceRules table that contains the headers:

**RuleID | CustomerID | Product Code | Category | Price | Percentage | DateApplied | AppliedBy**

The plan is to store the different variables in each column and then search based on the columns.

I'm sure this sounds really confusing so I will be around to answer queries as quickly as possible.

Thanks in advance,

**Bob P**

Comment: Maybe a stored procedure would work best for this since it requires conditionals and additional checks.

Comment: To make "finding which rule to apply" simpler, add a new column to your PriceRules table : DateExpired.  When you add a new rule, that takes over from an old rule you also update the old rule's expiry date.  This additional data integrity processing will make everything else MUCH simpler.

Comment: Continuation of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724346/rules-table-method-in-access-has-anyone-heard-of-it

Comment: @Remou Yes Remou it is, I have kind of hit a wall with getting this off the ground.

Comment: Do you need `Category` to determine the price for a product plus customer combination?

Comment: No Hans, the product codes are 100% unique and so they can determine the products price alone, however users may want to apply the discount to an entire category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get these results using SQL JOINs:

```
SELECT ...
Product.ProductPrice as Price,
CustomerRules.ProductPriceRules as Rules
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN Customer
ON ...
LEFT JOIN CustomerRules
ON Product.ProductID = CustomerRules.ProductID
AND Customer.CustomerID = CustomerRules.CustomerID
```

LEFT JOIN will return ONLY matching results if any exist, if record does not exist all CustomerRules fields will contain NULL values

Comment: And if their are multiple rules, with different DateApplied values?  *(I don't know Access' intricacies, I don't even know if it supports correlated sub-queries.)*

Comment: @Dems All DBs must (not always do though) support standard SQL. And all that is asked here can be done using standard SQL

Comment: Hi Germann, the rule will need to be applied if either the customer field in populated, the category field is populated or the product field is populated, is this also possible?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. Just get ALL fields that you need in your calculation and then use functions http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/index.php to calculate required result.